# How to install python 3.6 in your Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: python, azure

I am creating a serverless function with the help of python. but when I try to enable it it says you have python 3.5.

how do I install python 3.6 on the azure cloud shell  that we access to at portal.azure.com?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to install Python 3.6 instead of Python 3.5 on Azure Cloud Shell, as the figure below.

[image]

Let's first check the OS version in Azure Cloud Shell via `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`, as the figure below.

[image]

According to the result of the figure above, I see it's an Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 version. And to check the filesystem information via `df -a`, as the figure below, I also see it's just an Ubuntu Docker image.

[image]

I tried to do the normal install operations of Ubuntu via `sudo apt-get install python3.6` or `apt-get install python3.6`, but failed because there is no `sudo` command and no root permission for the current user, as the figure below.

[image]

So the only workaround is to download a pre-compiled Python 3.6 release to install on it. The offical Python website only releases the archive file of source codes with `tar.gz` suffix, not pre-compiled version for Linux, it's too complex to cost long time to compile Python source code to get a Python runtime via `gcc` and its library dependencies, so finally I decided to install a `miniconda` release of Python 3.6, which comes from https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/, and what I used is https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh.

Here is my steps and screenshots.

1. Directly to download the installation shell file [`Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh`](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh) and install it via commands
   `wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh`
   and
   `sh Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

   [image]
2. The default installation path is `~` that absoluted path is `/home/<your username>`. You just need to configure the environment variable `PATH` via command
   `export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH`
   then Python 3.6 of Anaconda will works fine for you, as the figure below.

   [image]

Even you switch to `PowerShell`, to follow the figure below to do the operations also can use Python 3.6 of Anaconda.

```
# PowerShell on Azure Cloud Shell
cd ~
cd miniconda3/bin
./python -V
```

[image]

Comment: Dude, this is great, you saved me all the headaches. I'd upvote twice if I could

Answer (score 0):

Create your function.

Installing a site extension with an alternative Python version and configuring the handler mapping to use that installation by default..

- Go to "Platform features > All Settings > Extensions > + Add
- Install the "Python 3.6.2 x86" extension.
- Go to "Platform features > Applications Settings
- Add an handler mapping:
  extension : fastCgi
  processor: D:\home\python362x86\python.exe
  arguments: D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py

Azure Function - Handler mapping to use a specific python version

- Add an application setting called WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER and set its value to 0. This is necessary to work around an Azure Functions issue that causes the Python extension to stop working after the function app is unloaded.
- Save your app settings.

Also check this thread for further reference:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/519

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Hope it helps.